# Expression in VBA code for MS Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba

When there is only one record, this expression gives correct calculation, but when there are more than one record the values of last record calculated is reflected in all `Total_Time` (unbound text box).I have given on load and on open code of the report. Please help me.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [q_1ltduty]"
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
  rs.MoveFirst
  Do While Not rs.EOF
    'Assigning values of fields to varia
    strtime1 = Op_Time
    strtime2 = Cl_Time
    'This is a simple expression my code has some more detailed calculations
    strhrs = strtime2 - strtime1
    strtotalhrs = strhrs
    'Printing the variable in Total_Time textbox(unbound)
    Me.Total_Time.Value = strtotalhrs
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
  rs.Close
  db.Close
  Set db = Nothing
  Set rs = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [q_1ltduty]"
  Me.RecordSource = strSQL
  Debug.Print strSQL

  Exit Sub
  ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: So your question is...? I don't understand what you are asking. Please clarify what do you need

Comment: the value for each record is not changing the text box is only showing the last record value..

Comment: well, the way your code is defined, it's exactly what it's supposed to be. If you want the *total* (sum) of all the records, then you have to make a "running sum" in the loop: `strtotalhrs = strtotalhrs + strhrs`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `strtotalhrs` contains only the value of `strhrs` for one record, so each time you go through the loop, the value for the current record erases the value for the previous record. What you should do instead of erasing the value is adding to it.

Before the loop (if it has not already been done):

```
strtotalhrs = 0
```

then in the loop, instead of `strtotalhrs = strhrs`:

```
strtotalhrs = strtotalhrs + strhrs
```

and that should give you the sum total instead of the last value.

Comment: you got it,I do not want sum but seperate value for each record.

Comment: but a textbox can hold only one value (the result of a calculation, as you want to do here) : I thought you wanted the sum, but it seems that's not it; what do you want to put in that textbox ?

Comment: I want to print the difference of two time that is cl_time-op_time in the Total_Time textbox. As with each record the values of these two time is different,the text box is in detail section of the report.I am grateful for your response...Thanks but it has not solved my problem please help